# Postgres JSONB updating array of objects

Tags: json, postgresql

Hi I have Postgres table `tmp` consist `id (int), jsondata (JSONB)`, `jsondata` contain array of objects and I'm facing problem in updating & deleting those keys

```
id | jsondata
------------------------------------
1  | {"10": [{"d1": 1000, "d2": 2000}], "11": [{"d1": 100, "d2": 200},{"d1": 111, "d2": 222}]}
2  | {"10": [{"d1": 1000, "d2": 2000}]}
3  | null
```

I want to do following operations 
  1. Remove if `d1` has a value 111, where `jsondata` key `"11"` where `id = 1` 
  2. Append `{"d1": 11, "d2": 22}` to where `id = 1` and `jsondata` key = `"10"` 
  3. Append `"12": {"d1": 11, "d2": 22}` to where `id = 1` and `jsondata` key = `"10"` 
  4. add `"12": {"d1": 11, "d2": 22}` to where `id = 3`

Comment: probably will not work, PostgreSQL doku 8.14.2: (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-json.html) ...keep in mind that any update acquires a row-level lock on the whole row.

Comment: Normalize and all that will become natural.